# TFS 2013 View member photo (Avatar)

Tags: visual-studio, avatar

I have TFS 2013 setup and it linked to mt AD group members. The member list appears OK, but I am unable to view the photo or my avatar, is this feature available? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add avatar to one member.

On the TFS portal, click the member name on the right-top corner, and select **My profile**. Then on the USER PROFILE page, select change picture link to choose the phone you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this wasnt what i looking for. In my environment, I assigned user access via Microsoft Exchange AD Group, and in that AD Group, there is a profile photo, which can be viewed via Microsoft Outlook. I just wan to link TFS to that profile photo of AD Group. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan, you have to add the photo manually on TFS portal with the method in my reply. TFS will not sync user account's photo from AD.